# Div not stretching - overlapping content below

Tags: css, html

I have tried and tried but cannot get the div with content to push the other divs down so that there is not an overlap.  Obviously new to CSS and could really use someones help.  The page in question is located at http://internet-icg.com/franco/news_mike.html.  You'll see what I mean.

I simply need the div's below the content to be pushed down acording to the height of the div above.

Thank you.

Comment: just by taking a look at your code I am not entirely sure what the intended effect is. Are you looking to have a static header and footer with moveable body that does not overlap on the header or footer?

Comment: You have the content div positioned with absolute, which does not take up any space and will not push down content. You could use a background-image on the parent div and float the content and sidebar next to each other instead of positioning them absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

ok.
Remove this line

```
<img width="1100" height="864" align="left" alt="immaculate reception" src="images/franco_03.png">
```

In the CSS change the position to relative (instead of absolute) in here

```
image .text {
    color: #CAC6B9;
    font-family: "Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: 65px;
    top: 0;
    position: relative
    width: 765px;
}
```

and change the absolute position to relative, plus add a float left here:

```
.image .text_social {
    color: #CAC6B9;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: 85px;
    position: relative;
    top: 16px;
    width: 220px;
}
```

Does this look more like you want?